# C# Comparer.Default<short>.Compare and Comparer.Default<byte> doesn't return -1, 0 or 1

Tags: c#, byte, short, icomparer

What's the reason behind all "numeric" comparers (such as `Comparer.Default<int>`, `Comparer.Default<long>`, etc.) returning either `-1`, `0` or `1`, but `Comparer.Default<short>` and `Comparer.Default<byte>` will return the difference between the two compared numbers?

Is it an optimization feature (returning the difference being faster) and/or because the possible difference between two shorts or two bytes will fit into an `int` (the `Comparer<T>.Compare` return type)? But the difference between two `ints` will not (`Comparer<T>.Compare(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue)` for example)

Comment: The most upvoted answer provides a good explanation, so I see no reason to close this question (clearly it is not too broad).

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [comments in the code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,65) it is the latter:

> ```
> // Need to use compare because subtraction will wrap
> // to positive for very large neg numbers, etc.
> ```

For example, say we had the same implementation as `short` or `byte` for `int`:

```
private int Compare(int x, int y)
{
   return x - y;
}
```

Now, the `IComparer` contract states that if the result of `Compare` is:

- Less than zero, then x < y;
- Greater than zero, then x > y;
- Zero, then x == y;

But, given the implementation above, if we pass a sufficiently large negative integer as the first argument, the subtraction will overflow and wrap to a really large positive number:

```
Compare(Int32.MinValue, 1); // returns 2147483647
```

That is the result would incorrectly indicate that `Int32.MinValue` is greater than `1`.

Given that `IComparer` is defined as:

```
public int Compare (T x, T y);
```

That is, the result type is an `int`, it is safe to just perform the subtraction of the arguments `short` or `byte` as it will never cause the `int` result to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it exactly right. An int difference does not fit into an int but a byte difference always does.

The return value of `Compare` is specified to only matter regarding the sign. Therefore, it is a valid and useful performance optimization to return the difference of `x` and `y` for smaller types.

In case you are interested: Other languages do not necessarily follow the sign model (`< 0`, `0`, `> 0`) at all. Some, such as Haskell, return an enum that has the three possible values `Less, Equal, Greater`. This is cleaner but slower.